# php if empty else quotes symbols

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am new to PHP
I am trying to display a word if the field in MySQL is empty or to display the text in the DB field if not empty but it give me error in Dreamweaver and display a blank page in browser, there is an error but cannot find out where.

What I need is to see what are the error symbols in the following code

```
 <?php if(!empty($mostrar['proveedor'])){echo
     "<?php echo $portal['cliente']?>";
    else {echo "<?php echo $mostrar['proveedor']?>";}?>
```

Comment: simply use `echo $portal['cliente'];`. You don't need to open php again

Comment: And you're missing a `}` use `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Also, that `if` states, _if `$mostrar['proveedor']` is NOT empty then do something, else, if it IS empty echo it_... Probably not what you intended.

Comment: Working perfect Liora